# Firestore startAt with timestamp field not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to paginate chronologically by **created_at** field (type of this field is **timestamp**), but the problem the following query with start_at return null, despite I have data after the given date (created_date).

```
  snapshot = await FirebaseHelper.FirebaseContext.firestore()
      .collection("Announcements")
      .orderBy("created_at", "desc")
      .startAt(1617235200000) // --> not work
      .limit(3)
     // .where("created_at", ">", 1617235200000) --> this not work also
      .get();
```

With startAt result is NULL !

Without startAt I got results

[image]

[image]

From docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors
[image]

If I use other field for pagination (for example the ID) it works !
This reproduce just with **timestamp** field

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: Please edit your question to show a document that you'd expect to get back from this query, but that isn't being returned.

Comment: Instead of epoch, can you pass an instance of Date and see if it returns result?

Comment: I tried that but not works :/

Comment: Enclose those values inside single or double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an actual timestamp to your `startAt` method like

```js
startAt('1617235200000')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
.start_at({"timestamp":datetime.datetime.now()})
```